# How is Stack Overflow developed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Years ago I started an FAQ website and could improve it a lot. It does not deal with the same subjects as this site, but Stack Overflow is amazingly well done in terms of usability, so I wondered: how it is developed? JQuery mainly?

Comment: jQuery is just a framework, I would say that the key to it is successful UI design/decisions/implementations.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Comment: Read their blog..

Answer (score 1):

With love and lots of attention to detail.

In all seriousness, there's [quite a bit of information out there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network) and you could do a lot worse than take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ for some of the behind the scenes (except it's not, as they're admirably open) discussions.